# Issue in javascript loader

Tags: javascript

I am having a strange problem i.e., when I am opening my website a loader is loaded and then homepage displays. Now I am navigating from home page to different page, everything is fine . The problem arises when I am getting back to the home page the loader is again loading.
In normal situation it should not load.  Not able to find out the reason. I am running the website locally so cant provide the url

window.onload() I have used.

Answer (score 0):

The Window.onLoad() event ALWAYS triggers when the page finishes loading.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

What is the reason to think that going to your page won't trigger onLoad() the second time?  The browser won't know the difference whether it is the first, second, or 500th time.